# Another word for 'not decorated as much'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to describe a room that my character walks into. I want to say that this room is similar to an earlier room I described, but none of the ornate objects are present (it is a simple room). So I would say

> The room was just like the throne room, only less *[word]*

or alternately

> It was roughly the same size as the throne room but lacked the *[word]*

What would that word be?

Comment: "... only less *lavish*." "... but lacked the *pizzazz*."

Comment: Less extensively (or elaborately) decorated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Unadorned](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unadorned)* or *[austere](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/austere)* (but *unadorned* is better).

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved with an explanation of  *why* you believe these words are suitable, including such references and examples as may be appropriate. Adherence to conventional orthography is also a plus. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a better understanding of how this site operates.